# Creating a link to close an element that fades in with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I created a notification at the top of the page that fades in:

HTML/PHP:

```
<?php if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
    <div class="notification">
        <span><?php _e( 'Welcome to Taiwantalk' ); ?></span>
    </div><!-- #container -->       
<?php endif; ?>
```

CSS:

```
   .notification {
        background-color: #444;
        color: #FFF;
        height: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        padding: 8px 0 0;
    }
```

JS:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function() {

  $j(".notification").animate({
    height: "22px",
    opacity: 1
  }, 1000 );

});
```

Now I would like to create a button at the right that closes the div with the same animation that it was used to make it fade in.

Any suggestions of how to accomplish this?

Comment: If you're going to use jQuery in no-conflict mode, remember to use `$j` everywhere you would have used `$` -- you are mixing the two in the code you posted.

Comment: Or use: `$j(document).ready(function($) {` Like in my demo

Comment: @Cory ... Not everywhere... (you want alexchenco broke his fingers typing '$j' just everywhere?! ) ;)

Comment: @roXon: You assume that that code within the `$j(document).ready(function($) {})` is never going to move. If you were going to move that code to its own function outside of that scope then it breaks. In terms of simplicity I think it's easier to just use `$j` everywhere instead of mixing the two. And about the broken fingers, just think how much typing jQuery is saving you already! One more character here and there isn't going to break anybody's fingers.

Comment: Thanks Cory, i appreciate your comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Practically the same thing as you already have. Just set height to 0px instead and opacity to 0. Assuming you want it to slide up and fade out. If you just want it to fade out then set opacity to 0. You can also use the jQuery fadeIn/fadeOut methods.

```
<input type="button" value="click" id="mybutton" />

//note that $j is relevant to the asker's code example. Typically jQuery just uses $. 
//See Roxon's answer for an example.
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function() {

  $j(".notification").animate({
    height: "22px",
    opacity: 1
  }, 1000 );

  $j("#mybutton").click( function() {
    $j(".notification").animate({
      height: "0px",
      opacity: 0
    }, 1000 );
  });

});
```

Comment: @alexchenco - in your `$(document).ready()` just below the `$j(".notification")` code block. I'll update my answer so that you can see. The button code goes in your main html document.

Comment: +1 mrtsherman... nice example! (P.S. As the OP did not checked my answer as correct... and it will not be on top of other answers, please consider (for future generations learning jQuery) to beautify the |`$j`| ) :) Happy coding!

Comment: good point. I just added comments to my answer to look at your answer. I want it to be relevant to the asker's posted code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the same animation, just use the original values in `.animate`.

```
$('#close').click(function() {
    $(".notification").animate({
        height: "0px",
        opacity: 0
    }, 1000);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Xzzra/

Answer (score 1):

### [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/LMBCU/4/)

[image]

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function($) {


    var notifiH = $j('.notification').height();
    $('.notification').animate({top:'0px', opacity:1},1000);
    $('.notification_close').click(function(){
        $('.notification').animate({ top:'-'+notifiH, opacity:0},1000);
    });


});
```

Comment: for some reason I can't click the close button.

Comment: Your link is bad roXon. Switch it to `/2/` instead!

Comment: @mrtsherman I did! Thanks! I was playing with the demo and right about to change to /2/ :)

Comment: I don't know why people insist you broke your fingers typing '$j' just everywhere. Nonsense. Alex... just use `$` inside your `ready function` like:  `$j(document).ready(function($) {` than USE NORMALLY your favourite `$`.

Comment: @roXon yeah, I think it is more advanced than the other reply.

Answer (score 0):

I would animate toggle a class instead of setting the height and opacity.  You could do this on the document ready event as well.  This allows you to keep your style separated from  your functionality.

Something like this:

```
$( "#close_button" ).click(function() {
        $( ".notification").toggleClass( "notificationVisible", 1000 );
        return false;
    });
```

and in your css, just have this:

```
.notificationVisible { height: 22px; opactiy: 1; }
```